# Why does Mola Ram only use the village kids for slave labor?

Tags: plot-explanation, indiana-jones, indiana-jones-and-temple-of-doom

In *Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom*, why does Mola Ram only use the village kids for slave labor and not the adults too?

Using the adults as well would benefit them much more.

Does he just think that children make better workers than adults twice their size and strength?

Comment: It is historically relevant to have children doing mine work as they are smaller, can go in tiny holes, crouch.

Comment: And if Mola Ram is planning to eventually conquer all of India and maybe the world, why does he steal child slaves from only one village in India instead of from countless thousands of villages? maybe Mola Ram grew up in that village and has bad memories of it.

Comment: Kids are more curious than adults to find hidden things, especially when things are mysterious with special powers. Kids in the mine use low food than the adult, and this is good for Mola Ram to save food storage as well. Kids occupied less space, room, facilities than the adult. Also, I guess Lucas and Spielberg enter kids to the story to give a fantastic atmosphere that suitable for teenager viewer and Indiana Jones series fans, and replacing with adult slave workers could change the atmosphere to serious and almost more violence that suitable just for adult viewers.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the mind-control blood/serum works better on children/those of weaker mind? Indy was able to be "broken out" by Short Round quite easily, so maybe Mola Ram primarily used the serum on children who, even if partially "broken out," would be too terrified to fully resist anyway.

Then, Mola Ram, in his arrogance, didn't think that Indy would be able to escape from the serum's influence. Or, maybe he underestimated the bond he had with Short Round.